# Problems with CoInitializeSecurity

Tags: c++, c, node.js, wmi

I have a module for C ++ which receives data from the WMI module asynchronously. But if you ask him a few times in a row, I get this error and get an answer only on the first call. How can I fix this?

```
Security must be initialized prior to the transmission or reception parameters.
Changes can not be made after the initialization.
```

Comment: So where is that module?

Answer (score 1):

Just run into this problem today. This error message means **CoInitializeSecurity** has already been called (it should be called only once per process).

I fix it by adding a flag indicating whether **CoInitializeSecurity** has been called or not, this flag is set when **CoInitializeSecurity** is called the first time, by checking the flag the subsequent calls can be avoided.

Considering multithreading you may need to add an exclusive lock to this code block.